# Batch file Nested IF statement help - CMD Batch

Tags: shell, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I'm currently in the process of writing a simple batch file. I'm not new to programming, but by no means an expert. This is the first time I've used batch files.

Basically I want a file from one directory to be moved to another, and, if there is already a file with the same name in the target directory, it will rename it as a backup. This way it will always keep a backup in case this script is accidentally run.

After hours of troubleshooting my code, I still don't know why It doesn't work. I suspect it's something to do with nested if statements. An If statement inside an if statement (for a lack of a better explanation).

I would appreciate the help. Thanks

```
  @echo off

REM Variables
rem dir1 is the source directory
set dir1=C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Dir1\
rem dir2 is the target directory
set dir2=C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Dir2\
rem file is the name of the source file and desired name of the target file
set file=file.txt
rem pre1 is the name of the copy of the old target file before it is overwritten
set pre1=push backup
rem pre2 is the name of prefix for a temporary file created in the target directory
set pre2=temp

REM if source file exist
if exist %dir1%%file% (
    rem if there is a file named the same in target directory
    if exist %dir2%%file% (
        rem if there is allready a backup file
        if exist %dir2%%pre1%%file% (
            rem rename the backup file as a temp file
            rename %dir2%%pre1%%file% %dir2%%pre2%%file%
            rem rename the old file as backup file
            rename %dir2%%file% %dir2%%pre1%%file%

            rem move source file to target directory
            move %dir1%%file% %dir2%

            rem if rename failed
            if not exist %dir2%%file% (
                rem rename the backup to the normal file
                rename %dir2%%pre1%%file% %file%
                rem rename the temp file to the backup file
                rename %dir2%%pre2%%file% %pre1%%file%
                rem echo error
                echo rename error
                pause
            rem Delete temp file
            ) else ( del %dir2%%pre2%%file% )
        )
    ) ELSE ( move %dir1%%file% %dir2% )
) ELSE ( echo %file% does not exist in directory "%dir1%" )
pause
```

Apologies for my sloppy commenting.

Comment: Please show error that you are getting on the console

Comment: I'm not getting an error, If there is a file.txt in dir1 and dir2 it will not move the file over. Probably because the file already exists which is why I had it rename the file.txt in dir2 to "push backup.file.txt" so I think I have the else or indents wrong at some point, I don't know where.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You see @echo off at the beginning of your batch file. Comment it with REM and reexecute to see the error on console.

Comment: As it stands, your question contains no clear problem statement, and the example code is not minimal.

Comment: Thanks savasa, It shows a The syntax of the command is incorrect. I assume this is referring to the two rename commands. Hear is a screenshot http://imgur.com/9S2XoaB

Comment: Have your closing paranthesis `)` at the end of each else in a separate line and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all your file references in double quotes. Spaces in usernames or file names will break most batch scripts otherwise.

E.g. your `pre1` variable is equal to `push backup`, which contains a space.

So your 3rd `exist` test:

```
if exist %dir2%%pre1%%file% ( ... )
```

Will translate to (evaluating the other variables and assuming username is jack):

```
if exist C:\Users\jack\Desktop\Dir2\push backupfile.txt ( ... )
```

This will check for a file named:

> push

in folder:

> C:\Users\jack\Desktop\Dir2\

And if that file exists, then the command that should be executed is:

> backupfile.txt ( ... )

By wrapping file references in double quotes:

```
if exist "%dir2%%pre1%%file%" ( ... )
```

You get the desired check:

```
if exist "C:\Users\jack\Desktop\Dir2\push backupfile.txt" ( ... )
```

Answer (score -2):

You are missing an else for the first IF and a right paean for the true on the first IF.

Should have ') else ()' to complete syntax.

For some reason they show now.

Add an else () for the one you don't have.

Comment: Why? `else ()` is redundant.

Comment: Missing one for one of the if statements. I think .bat likes all syntax to be present.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the indentation of the first if statement. There is one tab before the code under "if exist %dir1%%file% (".
I dont think else () will change anything and it appears to have no effect.